# Querying XML data in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, xml

With the code below I am trying to bring in an xml document to SQL Server Management Studio. The code runs but in the results page the row data comes out as all NULL's. Here is the code:

```
declare @xml xml

select @xml=d
from openrowset (bulk 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\NYairData.xml', single_blob) as data(d)

declare @hdoc int

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc output, @xml

select *
from openxml (@hdoc,'response/row/row',1)
with (
    _id varchar(100),
    indicator_data_id int,
    indicator_id int,
    measure varchar(1000),
    geo_type_name varchar(200),
    geo_entity_id int,
    geo_entity_name varchar(100),
    year_description int,
    data_valuemessage float)

exec sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

And here some of the xml data I am trying to use:

```
<response>
   <row>
     <row _id="1" _uuid="FDE5AC30-B86A-47C5-9A82-9333398F7898" _position="1" _address="http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/c3uy-2p5r/1">
        <indicator_data_id>130728</indicator_data_id>
        <indicator_id>646</indicator_id>
        <name>
            Air Toxics Concentrations- Average Benzene Concentrations
        </name>
        <measure>Average Concentration</measure>
        <geo_type_name>Borough</geo_type_name>
        <geo_entity_id>1</geo_entity_id>
        <geo_entity_name>Bronx</geo_entity_name>
        <year_description>2005</year_description>
        <data_valuemessage>2.8</data_valuemessage>
     </row>
```

The data is from the New York Open Data website. Here is a link to the source website: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Environment/Air-Quality/c3uy-2p5r. I am new to bringing in XML data to a DBMS. Here is a screen shot of the output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [OPEN XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql) docs and look at the examples therein.

Another good read: [XML Elements vs. Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_el_vs_attr.asp)

```
select *
from openxml (@hdoc,'response/row/row',2) -- 2 = Use the element-centric mapping.
with (
    _id varchar(100) './@_id', -- ColPattern to map _id attribute
    indicator_data_id int,
    indicator_id int,
    measure varchar(1000),
    geo_type_name varchar(200),
    geo_entity_id int,
    geo_entity_name varchar(100),
    year_description int,
    data_valuemessage float)
```